# tab completion using Term::Shell stops working after modifying the prompt

Tags: perl

Using this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

package Testsh;
use base qw(Term::Shell);

my @actions = qw/ a b c d e f g h /;

sub comp_cd {
    my ( $self, $action ) = @_;
    $self->completions( $action, \@actions);
}

sub run_cd {
    my ( $self, $action ) = @_;
    $self->prompt( "$action~> ");
}

package main;
my $shell = Testsh->new;
$shell->cmdloop;
```

When I start the shell, and press <kbd>tab</kbd> twice, I get three options: cd, exit help.

If I cd to one of the actions, then the prompt gets changed to the action name, but I no longer am capable of using tab completion. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented in [The Term:Shell API](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::Shell#The-Term::Shell-API), you can specify completions to `prompt` as the third argument:

```
$self->prompt( "$action~> ", '', [ glob '*' ]);
```

Comment: Thanks, really helpul. I will build a hash with possible values